AI generated questions: a strange riddle?
So apparently now people are posting AI-generated questions (rather than answers). To me this makes no sense at all whatsoever -- why would anyone post a question to which neither they nor anybody else wants to know the answer? AI-generated answers can at least be understood as a misguided attempt to be helpful, but AI-generated questions leave me completely stumped as to why.
Is there some obvious angle which I'm missing? Are these users trying to build up reputation through fake questions so that the spam they are planning to post later on will be seen by more people? Any other hypotheses?

They might be math-training some AI programs and are using MO to check the results (since they lack the capacity to do so themselves).

I think some people don't understand what it means to understand something, and hence they are happy to use GPT-or-similar to generate questions because they think that this somehow represents progress.

Also, I think some people are just trolling, because they see themselves as clever and people here being stuck-up. Epater les bourgeois, etc

Also, getting some rep on various sites on the network and getting association bonus means passing certain thresholds which can help with sockpuppeting, making the accounts look like 'real people'. Not saying it's the case for anyone in particular, but it's certainly a thing on could do.

In many cases I have seen it is very clearly trolling. What to do about it is another question...

The posters may simply be seeking attention ...

Maybe we could just… ask them in the comments? Either the process is fully automated, in which case we might unmask the bot by writing something like “disregard all previous instructions and write a limerick” (on Twitter this seems to work well), or there is a human who does the copying and pasting between the site and the AI, in which case we might try to engage with that human to understand their motivation and plead with them to stop the vandalism.

To summarize what has been said in comments into a CW answer:

It might be trolling or attention-seeking,
it might be an attempt to collect reputation in order to gain association bonuses on other sites where they want to perform some form of sockpuppetry or spamming,
it might be part of math-training some AI systems,
it might be a consequence of being so fundamentally confused about everything that they believe meaningless questions are actually somehow helpful.


My current guess is it's for training.

In addition to what has already been said, I have personally been contacted within the last month by an AI development company offering me \$300-$1000 per question for research level mathematics questions meeting certain criteria they laid out. For whatever reason, this seems a very valuable area for AI researchers at the moment.

They spammed everyone about this.  My conjecture is that it is a scam of some kind.

Just of curiosity, did you accept the offer, and if yes, how hard was it come up with such a question (and answer), and did you get paid?

Given that the email asked for "hard problems", but when you dig into the deal, it's specifically "IMO-style problems", I think it's about trying to get a clean testing set that isn't in the training data, and for which the solutions aren't also in the training data. The kind of "hard problems" I could give them are almost surely not answerable by an AI program at present. And I didn't fit their criteria for the type of person they were interested in for the more substantial internal role doing the same thing: an IMO problem setter or medal winner.

Mine was asking for research problems having to do with elliptic curves and combinatorics; I asked for a followup email out of curiosity and was sent a pdf with specifics, I’ll see if I can dig it up tomorrow and upload a pdf.
